# How to store values inside a Map and iterate through the Map in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to store the phoneNumber and their checkin time and when i am doing base on the 5 day data.i am unable to perform the desired output i have tried other methods also.can anyone suggest any solution to solve this problem.

```
  const start = momentTz()
    .tz("Asia/Kolkata")
    .subtract(5, "days")
    .startOf("day")
    .format();

  const end = momentTz()
    .tz("Asia/Kolkata")
    .subtract(1, "days")
    .endOf("day")
    .format();
  // o8iqzZl9NxQBcoOulFfH

  const addend = await db
    .collection(`data`)
    .where("timestamp", ">=", momentTz(start).valueOf())
    .where("timestamp", "<=", momentTz(end).valueOf())
    .get();

  const checkin = new Map();
  const timeArray = [];
  addend.forEach((doc) => {
    const time = momentTz(doc.get("timestamp")).tz("Asia/Kolkata").format("LT");

    timeArray.push(time);
    // console.log(timeArray);
    checkin.set(doc.get("ms_user.ms_phoneNumber"), timeArray);//this also gives a single value inside the array 
    checkin.set(doc.get("ms_user.ms_phoneNumber"), time);
  });
console.log(checkin)
```

it shows the output like this

```
 Map {
    '+9112345' => '10:20 AM',
    '+9112345' => '11:19 AM',
    '+91123456' => '3:23 PM', }
```

but i wanted the results in this format

```
 Map {
    '+9112345' => ['10:20 AM','10:45 AM'],
    '+9112345' => ['11:19 AM', '12:25 AM'],
    '+91123456' => ['3:23 PM'], }
```

Comment: what is the value of addend before you start looping over it ?

Comment: @HarmandeepSinghKalsi it's a snapshot of response which i am getting after the query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to check if the map is already having a value for the given key, if yes, then we need to get that value and append new time to add and then set it again in the map. If the key was not present we can simply set it in map with value as an array containing time.

```js
...
const key = doc.get("ms_user.ms_phoneNumber");
if (checkin.has(key)) {
   checkin.set(key, [...checkin.get(key), time]);
} else {
   checkin.set(key, [time]);
}
```

Comment: can you help me with one more point i want to pass the checkin in a function and wanted to extract the phoneNumber like this {'+12345' =>['11.00AM','12:00 AM']} because i don't know the exact number of phoneNumbers

Comment: You can iterate the checkin map using ````forEach````. Try ````checkin.forEach((key, value) => console.log(key, value));````